# Enable speaker during Linphone call in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-audiomanager

I was trying to enable speaker for my VoIP call using Linphone in Xamarin forms. I'm using the following code

```
public void PlayUsingEarSpeaker()
        {
            AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
           
            
            mAudioManager.Mode = Mode.InCall;
            mAudioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = true;
            mAudioManager.SetStreamVolume(Stream.VoiceCall, mAudioManager.GetStreamMaxVolume(Stream.VoiceCall), VolumeNotificationFlags.ShowUi);
            
        }
```

I have also added the permission for modifying the audio settings.

```
 protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        //RegisterReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("org.linphone.core.action.PUSH_RECEIVED"));
        System.Console.WriteLine("MyBroadcastReceiver registered");
        if (Int32.Parse(global::Android.OS.Build.VERSION.Sdk) >= 23)
        {
            List<string> Permissions = new List<string>();
            if (this.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Permission.Granted)
            {
                Permissions.Add(Manifest.Permission.Camera);
            }
            if (this.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio) != Permission.Granted)
            {
                Permissions.Add(Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio);
            }
            if (this.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.ModifyAudioSettings) != Permission.Granted)
            {
                Permissions.Add(Manifest.Permission.ModifyAudioSettings);
            }
            if (Permissions.Count > 0)
            {
                this.RequestPermissions(Permissions.ToArray(), PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
            }
        }
```

and in Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

I even tried to set the stream type to music but still my audio doesn't come from the phone speaker. I have no clue how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you set the communication device on AudioManager? See how Sipdroid does it: https://github.com/i-p-tel/sipdroid/blob/c03df8b020cbc3aa8d345934e2e1835ee8f6041b/src/org/sipdroid/media/RtpStreamReceiver.java#L381

Comment: @Cheesebaron No I have not set the communication device. I'm using Redmi note 8 do I have write any device specific code to play audio in speaker?

Comment: Seems like it, especially if you are on API level 31 and above

Comment: @Cheesebaron I have added permission you can check my edited changes.

Comment: That was not the code I pointed to... https://github.com/i-p-tel/sipdroid/blob/c03df8b020cbc3aa8d345934e2e1835ee8f6041b/src/org/sipdroid/media/RtpStreamReceiver.java#L396 Read it again, there is a method called `setCommunicationDevice`, to select the appropriate device to output sound to.

Comment: Did you check the official document about the linphone to find the method to set the audio's display channel?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I'm not able to get setCommunicationDevice method for my AudioManager class in Xamarin.

Comment: Even the AvailableCommunicationDevices method is also not found for AudioManager class in Xamarin. Is there a way for getting these methods in xamarin?

Comment: `SetCommunicationDevice` is exposed as a property `CommunicationDevice`, did you even explore what is available?

Comment: @Cheesebaron yes I explored there is no property called CommunicationDevice or AvailableCommunicationDevices in the AudioManager class in AudioManager class in Xamarin.

Comment: Uh, yes there is, I checked myself: `AudioManager am = AudioManager.FromContext(context); am.CommunicationDevice = comDevice;`

Comment: I'm still not getting the CommunicationDevice property I'm using using Android.Media; namespace for the AudioManager.

Comment: Only property I'm getting is am.GetDevices property which is related to Device.